# How to return subset of rows from Cassandra query?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spring-data-cassandra

How to limit the query result. I mean how to return subset of rows from cassandra table

@ Repository-

```
     @Query("select * from customer_request_v2 where product_id = ?0 and receipt_period = ?1")
     Page<CustomerReq>
     findByProductIdAndReceiptPeriod(String productId, String receiptPeriod);
```

Comment: Check out [LIMIT](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__specifying-rows-returned-using-limit).

Comment: I know we have limit option there to get subset of data from the requested cassandra table. But can we get any index value or something? Cos here am trying to return this data to my app layer where i need to implement pagination. Is there something that i can query start row and endRow like?

Comment: Maybe the [token](http://docs.datastax.com/en//cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html) function can help. Check out "[Automatic Paging](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0)" for more examples.